# asp.net c# if radio button is checked set label not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, radio-button, label

I have an extremely stupid query and was almost too embarrassed to post it. I have an asp.net web app made in C# and my issue is this, I have 4 radio buttons, i've grouped them, and when one is clicked, I want to set the text of a label below them.

I have multiple other pages in this project that use the same method and they all work fine but for some reason, I can't get the text to show when a radio button is selected. I have checked to make sure my i'm using all of the right names for the radio buttons/labels etc. Can someone take a look at my code and point out how stupid i'm being please? Thanks in advance!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Coursework
{
    public partial class Payment : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void poundRadBtn_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (poundRadBtn.Checked)
            {
                costLbl.Text = ("Testing");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you bound the `poundRadBtn_CheckedChanged` event to the control? Are you selecting the right radiobutton? `poundRadBtn`

Comment: are you familiar with PostBacks? you can do this several ways.. use UpdatePanel as 1 example do a simple google search on how to change label text in a web page during PostBack or you can write a simple Java Function etc...

Comment: Side-note: the parantheses in `("Testing")` are redundant.

Comment: you also do not need `( )` around the folloing Text `costLbl.Text = ("Testing"); `

Comment: Show the aspx code as well. The code shown isn't incorrect

Comment: I told you it was a stupid query, the one thing I had forgotten to check is whether my auto post back was set to true for each of my rad button controls.. Sorry to waste all of your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you have the property  `AutoPostBack="true"` in your `asp:RadioButton`

```
<asp:RadioButton id="poundRadBtn" runat="server" **AutoPostBack="true"**>
</asp:RadioButton>
```

Comment: Yup, as I said above, I was checking everything else but forgot to check whether my auto post back was set to true for each of the rad button controls. Thanks Pedro, sorry for wasting your time. I'll make yours the correct answer.

Comment: No problem @ACostea! Happy Codings! =)